# ServiceStack use the same "model" to multiple services

Tags: c#, routes, servicestack

I am new to ServiceStack and I am not currently familiar with the structure on how to develop a good API. I am trying to use the same Player model to do 2 separate things:

```
//POSTS SECTION
    [Route("/getplayernamechanged", "POST")]
    [Route("/getplayernamechanged2", "POST")] //I want to use this route to return a Player name concat with the string "just another test"
    public class Player
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class PlayerResponse
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }
    }

    public class PlayerService : Service
    {
        public object Any(Player request)
        {
            return new PlayerResponse { Name = request.Name+" just a test"};
        }
    }
```

How can I do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define two different request objects so ServiceStack can differentiate between the two requests.

```cs
// Route 1
[Route("/getplayernamechanged", "POST")]
public class ChangePlayerNameRequest : IReturn<PlayerResponse>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

// Route 2
[Route("/getplayernamechanged2", "POST")]
public class ChangePlayerNameAndConcatRequest : IReturn<PlayerResponse>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class PlayerResponse
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }
}
```

Then you need to make separate action methods to handle each of the cases:

```cs
public class PlayerService : Service
{
    // Route 1 handled here
    public PlayerResponse Post(ChangePlayerNameRequest request)
    {
        return new PlayerResponse { Name = request.Name + " something else" };
    }

    // Route 2 handled here
    public PlayerResponse Post(ChangePlayerNameAndConcatRequest request)
    {
        return new PlayerResponse { Name = request.Name + " just a test"};
    }
}
```

Note I have set the return type as `PlayerResponse` and defined `IReturn<PlayerResponse>` on the DTOs. This will ensure your metadata is correct. Hope this helps, let me know if you issues in the comments.

---

If you want to use the same `Player` model for the request objects then you could extend from `Player`:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

// Route 1
[Route("/getplayernamechanged", "POST")]
public class ChangePlayerNameRequest : Player, IReturn<PlayerResponse>
{
}

// Route 2
[Route("/getplayernamechanged2", "POST")]
public class ChangePlayerNameAndConcatRequest : Player, IReturn<PlayerResponse>
{
}
```

But it is best to avoid inheritance in DTOs where possible.

Comment: Thanks so much. That's what I've been looking for!